# data frame library in C++

Tags: c++

How might one implement data frame in R, Python, and other languages using C++?

Comment: There is none that I know of.

Comment: Try describing _exactly_ what features of R's `data.frame` you want in C++. At the moment only a complete duplicate or superset would be a valid answer, but you might be satisfied with less. Also, at the moment you'll only get answers from people who already know R.

Comment: @Useless, features like a DataFrame class that can handle both string columns and numeric columns, associated functions like which, subset, order, split, unlist, merge, tapply, ability to convert a vector or matrix into data frame, etc.

Comment: @Useless, your suggestion is very good. I should sit down and write the features I like. it might be easier to implement a mini version of R's `data.frame` in C++

Comment: `std::vector<std::tuple<>>`

Answer (score 1):

In general, `data.frame` solves a problem which is solved fundamentally differently in C++ (and other languages) – namely via class hierarchies, or, in the simplest case, via a vector of tuples.

Since you haven’t given specifics it’s hard to know what exactly you are after but if it’s ease of computation, [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) is a good linear algebra library for C++ (one among many). I haven’t yet found a good statistics framework for C++ – I suggest simply sticking with R for that.

Comment: yes I was looking for a C++ library that emulates R's data.frame closely. I use RCpp a lot to gain speed and in fact off late I have been using it so much that I felt why not migrate to C++ altogether.

Comment: Konrad this didn't really help. I am myself a *huge* Armadillo fan, but also aware that it *only* stores integer and double valued variables---no characters or strings, no factors, ... ---and aims *squarely* at linear algebra. I suspect you know enough R to know that `data.frame` is a very key R concept, and more general that (linear algebra) vectors and matrices.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, yes, that's true. I like the `data.frame` concept so much that I was hoping that someone might have worked on a library for C++.

Comment: @Dirk Sure. This is the closest that I know, though. You’ll probably agree that in other languages you would simply not usually use something like R’s `data.frame` but rather a vector of tuples or classes.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes because "would simply not [...] use" is due to most other languages not having data frames (or a close equivalent), and that holds for C++ too.  R is a language for programming with data; it covers things other don't really cover.

Comment: @Dirk I disagree with that. You can perform data queries very well on hierarchical rather than tabular data. Lisp excels at that, and so does Python. They don’t have a `data.frame` because they *don’t need* it, you can “program with data” very well without it.

Comment: @Konrad: The data.frame is a means to an end: almost all modeling functions take it as input. Lisp, Python, ... lack many/most of those modeling function.  But we are getting off-track: Let's recap that for C++, your answer was mostly incorrect, and I say that as a huge Armadillo fan and user.  May the (entirely useless) language comparison wars continue somewhere else...

Comment: @Dirk How do you feel about my earlier edit of the answer then?

Comment: @Konrad: Oh, missed that. It's better. You can nuke the last para though, the OP uses Rcpp already. But the spirit of mixing and matching comes through fine, so thanks for the edit.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I tried replicating my R codes to Python partially (in `Pandas`) to try it out, which was largely fine except every now and then there would be something that wasn't possible and I would revert back to R where I now know basics of `RCpp` whereas in Python, I have to work with Cython to make it faster (and the choice is `RCpp` vs `Cython`). `RCpp` probably allows everything to do in R via C++ and I like the flexibility of `RCpp`. My main motivation was that since off late I have started to use `RCpp` so much that I was exploring to use C++ altogether.

Comment: Also, I am trying to explore a massive machine learning trading strategy for which R was becoming a bottleneck with my current hardware and converting codes to `RCpp` was one way to resolve the speed issue. C++ would be natural place to look for speed, rather than Python.

Comment: You can also check out the xtensor tensor algebra libraries, which has a fairly comprehensive support of numpy APIs and supports missing values.